# difficulty with .jar file

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I am trying to create an executable .jar file. I create it and when I run it it is giving me the following error ==>

Failed to load Main-Class manifest atribute from 
C:\Users\Anastasov\Desktop\test.jar

where C:\Users\Anastasov\Desktop\test.jar is the directory of my .jar file and the name of the 
jar file is test.jar. I am following this tutorial by the way
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwVuK0X-0P0

Here are the steps of what I have done: ==>
so I first compile my class than I create myManifest.txt and specify where the main class is and it is in the Jdialogs.java and finaly i write in cmd:

```
jar cfm  test.jar myManifest.txt Jdialogs.class
```

Then the test.jar is created and is giving me the error from the top. If anyone is familiar with it and can help It would be appreciated Cheers.
Here is my Jdialogs.java code

```
   //Jdialogs.java
    //19.02.12

    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    class Jdialogs
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
       // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, titile is a string, messageType can be error info warning...);
          int answer;
          do
          {
          answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Can you see this dialog ?");

        // do something with the asnwer
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The confirm returned=" + answer,
         "Confirm Value", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );

        answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Rerun dmeo?", "Confirm Demo", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.out.println("Debug: Rerun Demo - Answer: " + answer);

          }while (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

      }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your actual manifest file as I'm thinking that the problem may lie in there.

Comment: Just open the jar file and check the manifest file and check for your main class.

Comment: Main-Class: Jdialogs   the name is myManifest.txt

Comment: And the myManifest.txt file contains...? Also, you should NEVER put any class in the default package.

Comment: Does the manifest file have a blank line at the end?  If not, it won't be parsed properly.

Comment: myManifest.txt contains: ==>  Main-Class: Jdialogs

Comment: @Kiril: you seem to be avoiding posting the text of the whole manifest despite many requests for it... why? Is that one line all that the manifest contains?

Comment: mhhh, this is the whole content of the manifest file ...

Answer (score 1):

```
 jar cfe test.jar Jdialogs Jdialogs.class
```

Should create the right -e entry point.

Comment: it is giving me : ==> 'e' flag and myManifest with the 'Main-Class' attribute can not be specified together

Comment: @Kiril: Sorry - I didn't test the manifest part. And thanks, I corrected my answer.

Comment: It is giving me the following error ==> "Could not find the main class: manifest. Program will exit "

Comment: @Kiril: I tested it with an own class and it works for me. Now I downloaded your code, compiled, used the jar command like above, and it works without problem.